# Получить список пользователей и время их последнего сообщения

Tags: php, оптимизация, mongodb

Нужно получить список последних сообщений пользователя (отправленные ему и им самим).

**Структура базы данных:**

**mail**

- _id
- from - отправитель
- to - получатель
- sdate - время отправки
- message - текст сообщения

На данный момент использую такой вариант:

```
$users = Array();
$mails = $db->mail->find(array('$or' => array(array('from' => $my['_id']),array('to'=>$my['_id']))));
foreach ($mails AS $msgs) {
     if ($msgs['from'] == $my['_id']) {
        $tUser = $msgs['to'];
    } else {
        $tUser = $msgs['from'];
    }
    $users[$tUser] = Array(
        "id"=>$tUser,
        "time"=>toTime(strtotime($msgs['sdate'])),
        "unix"=>strtotime($msgs['sdate'])
    );
}
function _sorta($a, $b) {
    if ($b['unix'] > $a['unix']) return 1;
}
usort($users, '_sorta');
```

Скрипт просто пробегается по всем сообщениям и записывает/заменяет уже записанное значение _id на массив с данными последнего сообщения и после чего сообщения сортируются по времени. Однако этот вариант не подходит, скрипт выполняется очень много времени, если пользователь получил более 1000 сообщений.

Собственно, нужно получить одним запросом список пользователей и последнее сообщение от них, не пробегаясь по всем сообщениям.

Comment: А это случайно тебе не как в ВК надо там на странице мои сообщения - все диалоги высвечены и в каждом диалоге последнее сообщение выведено?

Comment: @dantelol, да, нужно именно как в ВК :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать **агрегацию** в MongoDB, что-то типа такого:

```
db.mail.aggregate([
  {$match:{$or:[{from:my_Id},{to:my_Id}]}},
  {$sort:{date:1}},
  {$group:{
     _id:{from:"$from",to:"$to"},// можно оптимизировать? см. P.S.
     date:{$last:"$date"},
     message:{$last:"$message"},
     msgId:{$last:"$_id"}
  }}
]);
```

#### Что происходит в коде:

- Выберем все сообщения с `my_Id` в качестве отправителя или получателя
- Сортируем сообщения в порядке получения
- Группируем по составному ключу {`from`,`to`}
- В каждой группе в поле `date` записываем дату, а в поле `message` - текст самого последнего сообщения из отсортированных сообщений этой группы

Код написан "на коленке", под js-синтаксис утилиты mongo. Разберитесь в походе и реализуйте на своем языке.

#### Ссылки в помощь для изучения агрегации:

- [хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139643/) - много примеров самых разных видов, помогает понять суть агрегации, но под древнюю версию, когда агрегация только появилась
- [официальную документацию](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - примеры похуже, но более актуальная

---

P.S: Кажется, будут выбраны два последних сообщения - мне от друга и другу от меня.
Потенциальное решение - значением ключа делаем поле, в котором "не мы".

```
_id:(my_Id.equal("$to")?"$from":"$to")
```

`.equal()` - если `_id` имеет тип `ObjectId`. Но нет уверенности в корректности работы условного оператора в этом запросе и возможны проблемы при переносе на php

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался :)